# React - Dynamically rendering an image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I basically want to dynamically upload an image by concatenating the url with a variable which contains the name of the image:

```
<img src = {require(`./images/${imageStore[i]}`)}/>
// imageStore[i] prints the name of the image
```

As the comment above says, imageStore[i] prints out the name of the image (mars.png) if I were to insert the variable in something like a p tag. 
However I keep getting the error message:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module './undefined'.
```

Even weirder, when the app is initially rendered, I can clearly see the image present for a very short time before it errors with the error message, meaning it isn't undefined at all.

I am pushing the items in the array as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < image.length; i++){
      imageStore.push(image[i])
    }
```

I am not sure whether this is the problem however because I have done the exact same code with 2 other arrays and it has worked fine:

[Screenshot of how the app renders so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z2xx.png)

The other two are fields (TEST 1 and TEST2) are made with the exact same process, just without the `require`:

```
const Product = (props) => {
    var imageStore = []
    var nameStore = []
    var priceStore = []
    var mixStore = []
    let image = props.imageProps
    let view = props.foodProps
    let prices = props.priceProps 

    for(var i = 0; i < view.length;i++){
      nameStore.push(view[i])
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < prices.length;i++){
      priceStore.push(prices[i])
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < image.length; i++){
      imageStore.push(image[i])
    }
    var urlLink =  nameStore
    console.log(urlLink,'imageURL')
    console.log(image)
    for(var i = 0; i < nameStore.length; i++){
      mixStore.push(
        <div className='imageWrapper'>
          <div className='photo'>
            <img src = {require(`./images/${imageStore[i]}`)}/>
          </div>
          <div className ='nameHolder'>
            {nameStore[i]}
          </div>
          <div className ='priceHolder'>
            {priceStore[i]}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <div className='productWrapper'>
          {mixStore}
          <div className='priceWrapper'>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Any suggestions to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: so - `console.log(imageStore[i])` - chances are that is `undefined`, make sure you're not looping an empty element during the render cycle / prop / state change

Comment: also do a console on 'i' `console.log(i + ' '  +imageStore[i])` and share the results.

Comment: There is s possibilty that initially `imageStore[i]` is undefined and then the value is received and it works in the p tag but it will give an error with image source

Comment: When I console imageStore[i], it does show the image names, however when I console 'i' it does indeed show undefined:  "0 undefined".

Comment: BradRey update the question with the relavant code where you are using imageStore[i] and how you are pushing the data into that array

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need `require` here. Why not just do:

```
<img src = {`/images/${imageStore[i]}`}/>
```

Comment: When you use webpack you need to use require. Not sure whether the OP is using it or not

Comment: Doing it how Gleb Kost has suggested has removed the errors, but still does not render the image unfortunately, and no I am not using require in webpack I did see this as a suggestion but was unsure how to do it, do you know how do it do that ? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, could you show more code, pls? Where are you getting i from? Are you inside a loop? Or it's passed as a prop? Also, can you check the network tab in the devtools and see if it errors out when trying to load the image?

Comment: Yeah, basically I am using axios to bring the images to from the server which holds the image url (mars.png) from a mongo database. I then loop though images like this:  (`for(var i = 0; i < image.length; i++){
      imageStore.push(image[i])
    }`)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your(below) code.

```
<img src = {require(`./images/${imageStore[i]}`)}/>
```

Make sure that image path is inside of the BACK-TICKED string i.e `(which is placed besides the escape character).

if you still face the problem try share your code more understanding.

Comment: This is the issue I have, using the code above renders the image and I can clearly see it there, but after a second the app errors with the error I said before. I will update by question with more code to show how I pushed the items in the array.